# error in making JSON in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to make a JSON, but get a type error.
The error says, cannot set property 'apps' of undefined. This happens at the `*.isFav = true`
statement. If I remove the if statement it works ( the `isFavt(*)` statement).

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

```
        pref.userid =   username;
        //systems       
        systems =   [];
        for(i=0;i<system.length;i++)
            {
                systems[i]  =   new Object();
                systems[i].systemid =   system[i];
                systems[i].apps =   [];
                j = 0;
                $('.save label').each(function  ()
                    {
                        lst =   $(this).text();
                        console.log(systems[i]);

                        systems[i].apps[j]  =   new Object();
                        systems[i].apps[j].name =   lst;
                        systems[i].apps[j].href=    findHref(lst.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g,'_'));
                        //seq
                        systems[i].apps[j].seq  =   j;
                        //check for favourites
                        if(isFavt(lst))
                        systems[i].apps[j].isFav    =   'true';
                        else
                        systems[i].apps[j].isFav    =   'false';

                        //check for default
                        if(isDef(lst)   ==  true)
                        systems[i].apps[j].isDef    =   'true';
                        else
                        systems[i].apps[j].isDef    =   'false';
                        //subapps


                        j = j + 1;
                    });
            }
        pref.systems    =   systems;
        return  pref;
}
```

Comment: where do you make a json object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, your `isFavt()` function has a loop in it, that overwrites the `i` variable. JavaScript has *no* block scope and uses *global* scope if you do not declare your variables with `var`.

Replace

```
for(i=0;i<system.length;i++)
```

with

```
for(var i=0;i<system.length;i++)
```

and **do the same in your `isFavt` function**, because that is where the error comes from. Actually, do it with *every variable* you expect to be local to your function inside all your code.

Also, I highly recommend reading up on scoping in JavaScript.

Comment: This worked! You were right about the isFavt function. Gotta declare them vars the proper way. Thanks.